# How to create an in-memory image

Tags: python, cairo

I want to optimise my cairo drawing.  I have an unchanging background on top of which Cairo graphics is drawn.  The background can be different for each instance of the class so it cannot be a static file. To draw the background, I would like to do something like this:

```
    if self.pixbuf is None:
        self.pixbuf = self.draw_background(cr, width, height)
        #self.pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file("/path/to/file.png")

    cr.set_source_pixbuf(self.pixbuf, 0, 0)
    cr.paint()
```

So that I only create the background once and then display it as an image and draw things on top of it.  This is to save time instead of re-drawing the whole unchanging background every time someone else changes.  The commented out line of code works fine but I really do not want to create a png, save it to a temporary file, then load that file.  It seems like a waste of IO.

I tried this:

```
self draw_background (self, cr, width, height)
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, True, 8, int(width), int(height))

    cr.set_source_color(gtk.gdk.color_parse('black'))
    cr.set_line_width(2)
    cr.rectangle(0, 0, width, height)
    cr.stroke()

    cr.paint()
    return pixbuf
```

But no background is displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't your draw_background() function draw to the new pixbuf it creates? The code you pasted creates a new pixbuf, but doesn't draw anything to it. In other words: Instead of having a cr argument, it should create a cairo context for the new pixbuf. How much does this help?

Comment: @UliSchlachter: It might indeed but I cannot work out how to do it...  Most of the functions I found via Google search return `gtk.gdk.pixbuf_get_from_surface` which is not present on my system (pygtk v2.24).  Do you have a piece of code that does it I could have a look at?

Comment: I don't understand the "else" in your first code snippet. Doesn't that make it not draw the background to the widget when the pixmap is created for the first time?

Comment: @Ancurio: That is correct.  I want to draw it once then use the image I created.  I do not want to re-generate said images every time I redraw it.

Comment: @Sardathrion That's not what I meant. It looks to me like your background will only be drawn on the second frame.

Comment: @Ancurio: Ah I see what you mean...  Question edited.

Answer (score 1):

As Uli pointed out, you're drawing with the context pointing to your widget as the target, not your pixbuf. To create a new cairo context for a pixbuf, use [cairo_create](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkdrawable.html#method-gdkdrawable--cairo-create). Don't forget to destroy it when you're done drawing.